# Webcore NSBeep()! when copy from uiwebview

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, copy-paste

I'm developing an epub reader with monocle (https://github.com/joseph/Monocle) which is launched in a uiwebview. My problem is that when I try to copy some text, like what we would do in any other uiwebview, it doesn't seems to do anything... well, I get Webcore NSBeep()! in output view.

any idea or approach?

Comment: I have the same issue. It's driving me nuts. Could you solve that in the end?

Comment: i dont think it is related to UIWebView or anything directly related to your code. Even i have received this error sometimes ! But I cant reproduce the same error again !!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992581/webcore-nsbeep-in-console-when-debugging-an-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

Webcore NSBeep()! is a error notification, because when you try to copy text from UIWebview the text is not copied into your clipboard and the error notified using a beep (IMHO which is not wise way of notifying errorr by any platform, it would have been any visual indication)

And please note : NSBeep() is part of the ApplicationKit framework which doesn't exist on the iPhone.

Comment: Indeed NSBeep() does not exist on the iOS SDK, yet it is in the error log. Also, it's coming from the frameworks, so the question is: why is this message popping up and what can we do to prevent it?

Comment: You mean NSBeep() doesn't exist on the iPhone. Really? I was using iPad and I saw this error notification when I debug my app. It's not in iPad but still in iPad :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same strange issue, irritatingly enough everything worked for quite some time. Then with some changes, this error happened. Reverting the code did not help. After a whole day searching and thinking, I still don't know what caused this, but I know that it wasn't my code!

My theory is that either my git repository was somehow messed up or it was because I edited my project with a beta version of the IDE+SDK. Either way, you should probably look into recreating your webview in InterfaceBuilder. Or recreate your project (or at least partially to confirm that it might be a bug in the project itself). I think/hope that the error will go away then.