# Webcore NSBeep() in console when debugging an iOS App?

Tags: console, ios6, warnings

While I'm running my iOS 6 app on the iPhone I get this weird message in the console.

```
Webcore NSBeep()
```

I read in other posts that this NSBeep doensn't even exist in iOS. Beside I'm not using anything related to the web at all in my app. So what does that mean? Is that an error I should be worried about?

Comment: I'm getting the same? What is it!?

Comment: I did H2CO3's advice and ignored it. It's OK I guess.